# Preact application using socket.io and preact-context?

Tags: reactjs, redux, socket.io, preact, react-context

I recently started playing around with preact and am intrigued by the ease of use and the performance.   I have also been eyeing react's new context api (preact has a library [preact-context](https://github.com/valotas/preact-context) to operate the same way).

Are there any examples or applications someone can share/reference using preact that leverage combining socket.io and preact-context?

I am specifically looking to compare the "preact+preact-context" way as opposed to the "react+redux+router+thunk+saga+..." way especially as it relates to a SPA desktop-style application

The SPA application I am looking to build will be an MDI (multiple document interface) so not a content serving app where the state can all be held in redux.   We are finding also that doing things the "Redux" way is adding a lot of overhead and complexity to our code, so I am trying to see if there is a better method.

What I am hoping to understand from some provided examples:

- What would a SPA-type application look like without redux using context api?   (I guess this is the same for react & preact)
- What are the pros and cons of doing a SPA using context api?
- Can socket.io be used in a context api provider in some way?